# How do I just reference the Body field in a record?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a form a with a few simple fields and a rich text Body field.  I want to be able to just show the Body field (not the whole form) for a particular record.

For instance, this record has the url: https://script.google.com/a/macros/somecompany.com/s/AKfycbz-SGylT7XkQ0pZsC9DLCqBlaBVUrJrh9-weCGD4CFGmncrFD233fFP/exec?console=1&devConsoleProjectId=project-id-1608486759417312249#ViewSecurityPolicy/

I want to just show the Body field from the record.

A gif of myform is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxTPP.gif)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if you have multiple widgets that you need to show/hide depending on some condition, you can organize them and put into common panel and then do all the magic with that panel.

The basic approach to show/hide a widget is binding its `visible` property to some condition:

```js
@datasource.item.Id === '1'

or

@datasource.item.SomeFlag === true
```

If you want your widget to be hidden forever then just uncheck `visible` property checkbox or remove the widget from the page.

Comment: Say if I just added another form that just has the Text Editor Body field.  I've disabled the form for editing.  But I would like to not see the Text Editor controls at the top of the form (which do nothing anyway).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It worth a separate question.